# How can I determine which key was pressed on a Bluetooth keyboard using JavaScript in iOS 9.2 Safari when the keyup event object is empty?

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, bluetooth, keyboard-events

I have tried this with 3 different Bluetooth keyboards on the iPad Pro, and I got the same result with them all. One was the Logitech CLEAR iPad Pro keyboard case, one was the Apple Wireless Keyboard, and one was the iPad Smart Keyboard.

When inspecting the event object from a keyup JavaScript event, regardless of which key is pressed, I get no data in the event object to help me distinguish which key was pressed on the Bluetooth keyboard. Here is what I get from the event object:

```
{
    ...
    keyIdentifier: 0,
    keyCode: 0,
    key: undefined,
    charCode: 0,
    char: undefined,
    which: 0,
    ...
}
```

Of course, when I use the virtual keyboard within iOS, everything works just fine and I get the data I need.

Does anyone know of a way around this? Or are Bluetooth keyboards for iPad just crippled when it comes to web-based applications? :(